# Drupal Cache Issue - Theme breaks in IE when Aggregate is enabled

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, caching

I noticed that when I enable 'Aggregate CSS/JS,' my site's theme breaks in Internet Explorer (all versions). I did some troubleshooting and tried downloading the cached CSS files from IE. When they opened in Dreamweaver, I realized that the text was garbled and was showing non-latin characters in place of the CSS.

The site works well in Firefox and Chrome, but it seems IE is interpreting the CSS and JS differently I guess.

I've been trying to resolve this for the past week. Is this a server issue or an .htaccess issue? I made sure I wasn't enabling GZIP on top of the cache.

Any help is appreciated.